# SQL: generate incrementing integer based on value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

on SQL Server.

I am importing a table that looks like this:

```
ForeignID || Detail 
ID1       || detail1
ID1       || detail2
ID1       || detail3
ID2       || detail1
ID3       || detail1
ID3       || detail2
```

Into a new table that looks like this:

```
ForeignID  || ItemNo   || Detail
ID1        || 1        || detail1
ID1        || 2        || detail2
ID1        || 3        || detail3
ID2        || 1        || detail1
ID3        || 1        || detail1
ID3        || 2        || detail2
```

How do I automatically generate the "ItemNo" column values? 
They should be an auto-incrementing integer that get resets whenever ForeignID changes. ForeignID and ItemNo will act as Composite Primary Key for the new table.

It'll be great to be able to do this during the INSERT INTO - SELECT process. Otherwise, a separate query would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy task for ROW_NUMBER:

```
insert into target
select
   ForeignID
  ,row_number()
   over (partition by ForeignID order by Detail) 
  ,Detail 
from source
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using row number, something like this:

```
insert into ... 
select 
    ForeignID, 
    Detail, 
    row_number() over (partition by ForeignID order by Detail) as RowNum
order by
  ForeignID,
  Detail
```

The rownum will start numbering every time ForeignID changes